# Force a service to start before networking.service

Tags: networking, systemd, services

I would like to start my service `samplerbox.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts SamplerBox

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/root/SamplerBox/samplerbox.sh          # this script does: python /root/SamplerBox/samplerbox.py
WorkingDirectory=/root/SamplerBox/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**before** `networking.service` (DHCP thing, IP attribution, etc.) has finished.

*Remark: my program doesn't use networking at all.*

---

Here is the plot ([bigger size here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190716065717/https://gget.it/sb5sfgln/ets.svg)):

[image]

As you can see, `samplerbox.service` exactly waits for `networking.service` to be finished. (I did several tests, and it is the same).

I tried: replace `WantedBy=multi-user.target` by something else like
`WantedBy=sound.target`  and then `systemctl disable samplerbox.service` and reenable it... But this was unsuccessful!

**How to force a service to start before `networking.service`?**

Comment: [Here is the result](http://gget.it/gvysuj3p/test) of `systemctl show networking`

Comment: Have you tried `WantedBy=networking.service`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `samplerbox.service` is started after networking has finished.

True, but only an incidental and not what is actually happening.  If you look *carefully* at the graph you'll find that `samplerbox.service` is being started after `basic.target`.  This is normal and by design in systemd.  Most (non-system) services have "default dependencies" set, which are implicit dependencies and orderings that are not written out in the service unit.  A dependency from `basic.target` and an ordering after it is one such default that is applied by systemd, unless the defaults are explicitly disabled in the service unit.

You are also conflating ordering and dependency.  The various "wants" directives, such as `WantedBy` that you have been playing with and its reverse `Wants`, specify dependencies.  They make systemd queue a job to also start service B if a request is made to start service A.  They do *not* specify the orderings of those jobs.  Orderings are controlled by other settings, namely the fairly obviously named `Before` and `After`.

Dependencies specify what overall set of start and stop jobs is constructed from a simple command such as `systemctl start graphical.target`.  Orderings specify when and in what order those jobs are then executed.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`systemd.unit`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`systemd.service`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.

Comment: Thanks @JdeBP for this detailed answer. Now, for a solution : *how to force my service to run as soon as possible?*  If I `systemctl disable networking`,  my service starts @4sec, but if networking is still enabled, mu service starts @10 or 12sec, that's bad.    How to force my service to start before everything else?

Comment: Should I for example set `DefaultDependencies=false` ?

Comment: Solved with `DefaultDependencies=false`! Thanks so much for having pointed me to the right docs!

Comment: @Basj: you **shouldn't** set `DefaultDependencies=false` unless you precisely know what are you doing. For example, this may make your service start with read-only root filesystem, or before time is set up, or... whatever. Most probably, you actually want to remove the "sysinit.target is after network.target" dependency, it is strange and bogus. Removing this dependency will make all services start earlier and faster.

Comment: @intelfx Some other people told me the same, but I haven't found another real working solution. Do you have one? (if so I would be verrry interested by an answer).     You say  I should remove the "sysinit.target is after network.target" dependency, but I haven't modified *anything* (in systemd configuration) except my own service. So this dependency might be the Raspbian Jessie default value. What do you think?

Comment: @Basj: I don't use Debian, but if it's a default, then just go and override it. `systemd` has a convenient way to override any number of unit files.

Comment: @intelfx : what to do exactly to remove this default dependency?

Comment: @Basj: find the exact unit file (in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`) where it is specified. Copy it to `/etc/systemd/system` under the same name. Edit the copied file, removing the ordering dependency.

Comment: Debian unstable (sid) has systemd 215 and sysinit.target is indeed after networking.service. OpenSUSE 13.2 has systemd 210 and sysinit.target is not after network.service. Not sure who has changed that and why.